# I need administrator password for file management on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, password, external-disk, administrator

So I have an external hard drive, my passport, that used to be a Time Machine, but now I use for basic file storage. Whenever I try to add a folder, or manage files, it asks for an administrator password. I looked in the system preferences, and it said nothing about it there. Help.

Answer (score 1):

One question first: do you still use it for TimeMachine also? If not, did you format it before you use it for what you do now?

Comment: No. How do you format it?

Answer (score 0):

i think if its a volume dedicated to timemachine sure u "can" but u might not create nothing in that volume because its maintained by the timemachine system.   but u can split an external HD in several partition and allocate one to time machine, assuming the partition allocated has equal size of u system partion. others newly formatted partitions in fat on whatever wont need administrator rights read/write etc..

Comment: I don't still use it for time machine.

Comment: format it with disk utility.